# PHP Create file and delete it after one hour, one week etc

Tags: php, file

I want to create a file and can auto delete it after the necessary period.
My code is:

```
 $timeForDelete=$_REQUEST['timeForDelete'];
 $text=$_REQUEST["text"];
 $filename = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.txt';
 if($timeForDelete =="2"){
//how save text to file and  auto delete file after one hour?
 }
 else{
    $f=fopen($filename,'a');
    fwrite($f,$text);  //write to file
 }
```

if $timeForDelete ==2 : how can I save text to file and auto delete it after one hour?
Hope you help solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You gonna need a cron job that regularly checks for file created dates and deletes if necesarry

Comment: Can you  give the example , please?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do what you are requesting.
I would suggest that the quickest way to do this would be:

1. Creating the file with a name that is uniquely identifiable as
   needing to be deleted (and based on your question, perhaps a timestamp in the name after which they can be deleted - One hour, one week, etc.)
2. Write a script that will delete all files containing that unique identifier based on the time they were created.
3. Set up a cronjob to run the script every 5 minutes and clean up your un-needed files.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to give an example script that the cron would run.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Unfortunately on  Linux systems we can't get the file creation date, so `fmtime` is our best bet. For more info please read the wiki below `fmtime`'s documentation.

*Note: This is just a simple example*

**List all the files in a directory:(/path/to/your/script/yourscript.php)**

```
  //assuming files are stored in /path/to/your/script/myfiles
    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/myfiles';
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);
    //assuming all your files are in $paths top level

    foreach($files as $file){
        //unix time
        $ctime = fmtime($path . "/$file");
        //basic math
        if(time() > $ctime){
            unlink($path . "/$file");
        }
    }
```

**Your cron job**

*If you 're running a Unix like OS:*

Runs every 5 minutes. You can reconfigure

```
crontab -e
```

Add this to the crontab and save:

```
#invoke the intepreter
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/your/script/yourscript.php
```

Edit:

Alternatively you can save the upload times of these files in a database to keep track of file creation dates

Comment: You can put the file creation timestamp in the file name or deletion timestamps in easily identify them if you have variable deletion periods.
If you use a database to list files and deletion times this would likely be easiest.

Comment: Yes @O Genthe that's a solution

Comment: Mine is not the most elegent solution though @peter. This is really a very broad question here and a lot of work to get to a workable solution. You have put a lot of work into your answer and it will work best with a database component.

Comment: A database introduces another dependency. This might negatively affect the application s portability @O Genthe

Answer (score 0):

this code is 100% working

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\Register.php'; <'Enter Your delete file name'>

$creat_time = date("d-m-Y h:i:s",filemtime($path)); 

$endTime = strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($creat_time));

if(time()>$endTime){
    unlink($path);
}
```